# Does anyone remember how to play a card game called "Wreck Your Neighbor's House"?

Tags: identify-this-game

The card game was a little similar to Solitare but the set up of the cards was different.  My family and I used to play this game 20-30yrs ago with my grandmother but we have all forgotten how to play it, but would love to play it again!

Comment: what did the cards look like were they a-k or unknown type? how many cards distributed ? where there turns or jump into when meeting a criteria?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't remember. But, I know it wasn't set up in a crazy way like a pyramid or a diamond. I think there might have only been like 5 rows of cards, and one pile to draw from to the left of the row. I also know it was only a two player game.

Comment: I remember a similar name from my childhood and found this: https://www.dummies.com/games/card-games/playing-beggar-my-neighbor/ but there are no rows in that, you just turn things over, and any number of people can play

Comment: If you cannot remember anything further about the game - how will you identify a correct answer? As written, this is an unanwerable question.